# ¿Se Puede Usar una Base de Datos Local SQL SERVER Para una App Web (MVC 5)?

Tags: c#, mvc, sql-server-2017

Hola estoy  iniciando  con una Aplicacion Web (MVC 5)he trabajado  mas en App de Escritorio ¿Para Una Aplicacion Web se puede usar  una Base de Datos Local SQL SERVER o  es necesario alguna Base de Datos en la Nube  como  el que ofrece Microsoft Azure?

Comment: Respuesta rápida: Sí se puede. La pregunta ahora es ¿Cuándo?, si el sistema web va a estar solamente en una máquina local y/o en un entorno de trabajo de computadoras que comparten la misma red y pueden tener acceso a un servidor web, sí se puede, sí es posible. Ahora, si el sistema quieres que esté en internet, o bien levantas un servidor y lo configuras o bien utilizas servicios como SQL Azure; aunque existe la opción de tener tu computadora como servidor utilizando servicios como no-ip.com, te sugiero que los evites en entornos de producción. Saludos.

Comment: Por cierto, lecturas recomendadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: La idea es subirla a Internet ya que necesitan consultarla diferentes personas  de diferentes lugares, y  es que en todos los proyectos que he visto en Youtube Utilizan  una BD local pero  no  estoy  seguro  si  solo  es a modo  de ejemplo  o  con fines prácticos de producción

Comment: Es a modo de ejemplo, aunque de poder, se puede; inclusive con SQLite en un archivo y ya, el detalle viene con el paso del tiempo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola como estas? puedes utilizar la base de datos local o externa, te recomiendo buscar informacion sobre ADO y EntityFramework creo que eso seria lo que estas preguntando pero me queda duda, si lo que preguntas es si al lenvatar la aplicacion puedes usar la local en ese caso por ejemplo, si levantas el servidor y montas ahi la web y la bd, no vas a tener problemas, pero lo optimo para un ambiente de produccion es utilizar algun servicio cloud.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.